# python dynamic value in api payload

Tags: python

Hey i have an api request and i need the value in payload to by dynamic, i tried with f''  but it wont make it dynamic

will appreciate your help.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.stie.com/api/conversations/KJQ-CZHNR-985/fields"
valuetarget = "123"

payload = {'apikey': 'zbyc88srdi333d3dpq5lye48pgg1tfo1pnjvj65ld',
           'customfields': '[{"code": "orderno", "value":"valuetarget"}]'}
files = [

]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: i just cant make valuetarget  in the payload dynamic - as it consider it as a string there

Comment: Can try payload to json.dumps(payload) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the curly braces in the formatted string, like so:

```
f'[{{"code": "orderno", "value":"{valuetarget}"}}]'
```

But why not let `requests` format the string for you?

```
import requests

url = "https://www.stie.com/api/conversations/KJQ-CZHNR-985/fields"
valuetarget = "123"

# 'customfields' is now a list of dictionaries
payload = {'apikey': 'zbyc88srdi333d3dpq5lye48pgg1tfo1pnjvj65ld',
           'customfields': [{"code": "orderno", "value": valuetarget}]}
files = [

]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Perfect, the escape did the job.   Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to load json and dump it to string and send it.

```
import json
valuetarget = "123"
payload = {
     'apikey': 'zbyc88srdi333d3dpq5lye48pgg1tfo1pnjvj65ld',
     'customfields': 
          json.dumps([{"code": "orderno", "value":valuetarget}])
}
```